# wxWidgets on the ARM processor

Tags: linker, arm, wxwidgets

I am trying to use wxWidgets on the ARM processor. I configured wxWidgets as following:

```
../configure --host=arm-linux --with-gtk --with-libpng=builtin --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin --with-regex=builtin --with-zlib=builtin --with-expat=builtin LDFLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" --enable-unicode --with-opengl --enable-mediactrl
```

Running `make` compiled it just fine and then I installed it using `sudo make install`.

However, when I tried to build an app with it, I get the following linker errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu-3.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_gtk3u_media-3.0
```

Comment: How do you build the program exactly? Which `wx-config` is being used?

Comment: I solved this as well. When the program was installed, some symlinks were not created. Perhaps I needed to do a post-build step. I used the `configure` script and then did `make` and `sudo make install`. Is there some post build script I should have used?